# building python C++ extension -- how to know if a linked library cannot be found

Tags: python, distutils, python-extensions

I downloaded a python-wrapped C++ code and am trying to build it from source, and it compiles without errors, but when I run the end result, it fails in a way that seems to suggest that it did not find at least one of the libraries that it was supposed to link against.

What surprises me is, in `distutils.core.Extension`, you can give a list of libraries, but there is no error or message to tell me that one of the libraries does not exist. I can put any gibberish string in the list and it will still run without errors. Is there any setting for this in `Extension`? Or any other way to check?

For reference, here is the `setup.py` code (Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7):

```
coolmodule = Extension('cool',
    sources = [
        'cool/main_python.c'
    ],
    libraries = [
        'cool',
        'stdc++'
        'lapack',
        'blas',
        'gfortran',
        'fftw3',
        # if I add any gibberish string to this list,
        # it still runs without error!
    ],
    library_dirs = ['./build'],
    extra_link_args = [
        './build/libcool.a'
    ]
)

setup(name = 'cool',
    ext_modules = [coolmodule]
)
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating a shared library that you import as a Python module? If so, you can use the `ldd` utility in Linux/Unix to see the shared libraries required by your module. On Mac OS X, the equivalent tool is `otool -L`

```
(test)MacBook-Air-2:foo talumbau$ otool -L foo_ext.so
foo_ext.so:
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
        /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2577.0.0)
```

If the shared library requires other libraries and they aren't found, `ldd` or `otool -L` will show you which ones. You can then track them down and modify your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that they will be linked it at load time.